# How to get 2 different sized text to both float to the same height?

Tags: html, css

[image: Visual respresentation of the problem]

So in the picture you can see that the number "5384" and the number "50" dont float to the same height. I know that the paragraphs both float to the exact top of the line but how do i get them to look like they're on the same height?

I don't want to use "margin-top: some pixels" because that wouldn't scale properly would it?

```css
.savings {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.savings_cents {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.3rem;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<p class="savings">5.384</p>
<p class="savings_cents">50</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> This can easily be achieve using `sup` html tag

Read more about this tag here

```css
p{
   font-weight: bold
}
p sup{
   font-weight: normal
}
```

```html
<p class="savings">5.384 <sup>50</sup></p>
```

*You can easily style that using tag or classes*

Answer (score 0):

**Just add a parent element and use display: flex.** You can check both elements height is same. You can use other flex properties to change the alignment if you want.

```css
p{margin: 0;} /*resetting p margin*/
.savings-ctnr {
    display: flex;
}
.savings {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.savings_cents {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="savings-ctnr">
    <p class="savings">5.384</p>
    <p class="savings_cents">50</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can inspire from tag `<sup>`, make `<span>` with class `savings_cents`, wrap it with element with class `savings` and make something like this:

```
.up-small {
  vertical-align: super; /*make element to be aligned with the superscript baseline of the parent*/
  font-size: 50%; /*fits proportions*/
}
```

Example look into snippet

```css
.savings {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.savings .savings_cents {
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p class="savings">5.384<span class="savings_cents">50</span></p>
```